# Determine the type of query based on the query string

Tags: php, mysql, string

`$query1 = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = ?';`

`$query2 = 'UPDATE table SET field = ?';`

How can I detect if the query modifies the database, or just requests results from it?

Is it enough if I do a strpos for `SELECT` (if it's found then query is read-only) ? Or are there other situations I need to handle?

Comment: I don't think checking for SELECT is a good idea since SELECTs can be used in sub-queries. Anything that contains UPDATE, however, definitely modifies the database

Comment: Think about `update table set col1 = (select abc from tab2)` and so on

Comment: what about `if(strpos('SELECT', $query) === 0) $is_read_only = true;` ?

Comment: You're not wanting to know this in order to implement some kind of permissions control, right?

Comment: There are other queries that return a resultset such as SHOW, EXPLAIN, DESCRIBE. I am assuming you want to detect before running the query?

Comment: @jonathan - no. I'm building a simple db API, and need to determine what should I return

Comment: "Anything that contains UPDATE, however, definitely modifies the database ". To be a pedant, the statement `UPDATE some_table SET col1 = col1 WHERE 1 = 0` definitely *doesn't* modify the database. Also `SELECT 'UPDATE' FROM UPDATES WHERE UPDATED=1` also doesn't. :-)

Comment: Look for `UPDATE` and `SELECT` at the beginning of the string, exclude any whitespace. Better, use an SQL parser.

Comment: Surely you just need to look at the first verb? In a query that returns results, the *first* verb will always be a `SELECT` (or `SHOW`, `EXPLAIN`, `DESCRIBE` or whatever) and in a query that modifies the database the *first* verb will always be `UPDATE` (or `INSERT`, `DELETE` or whatever) - so all you need to do is look at the first "word" in the query, and maybe `switch` it against a list of allowed verbs (which you can get from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)) and handle accordingly. Or is there something I have forgotten there?

Comment: Although having said that, whatever approach you take will get *very* complicated if you need to handle conditional statements, transactions or loops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's mysql ..

`mysql_affected_rows()` shows the number of rows that were affeced by an insert/delete/update etc whilst `mysql_num_rows()` shows you how many were selected.  Depending on which function returns a value you should be able to determine the kind of response.

Comment: The OP is quite clearly asking how to determine this *without* running the query - please read the question and the comments properly before answering.

Comment: Not sure that you're right there - the OP is asking to determine how to respond to the query .. see comment above : @jonathan - no. I'm building a simple db API, and need to determine what should I return .. I interpret that as : "I worked and updated 100 records" or "here are the records I found".

Comment: Even if that is true, a simple `is_bool()`/`is_resource()` (or `is_object()` depending on driver) check would be a more reliable way to determine whether or not you have results to return. `mysql_affected_rows()` will still give a result after a `SELECT`, even if the docs don't say it will.